# Count the related objects of a related object

Tags: django, count

I got 3 models:

- Town
- Building
- Upgrade

Upgrade keeps track of a building that is being upgraded.

```
class Town(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)


class Building(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(BuildingTemplate, related_name='building_template')
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town)
    level = models.IntegerField()


class Upgrade(models.Model):    
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    timer = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I want to count the amount of buildings that a town has in upgrade. Now I guess I could do this with some for loops, but I wondered if there wasn't a better way by using the Django API.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation

Comment: Not sure about the data structure here. What does it mean for a building to have many Upgrades?

Comment: Good question, i might include that already in the building itself.  On the other hand,  im not sure yet if i want a building to be able to upgrade 2 things at once. so i kept it separated for now. Maybe not best call indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer will count the same building multiple times if they have multiple upgrades. Use this instead:

```
count = Building.objects.filter(town=town).exclude(upgrade=None).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out with the linked documentation that this works for me:

```
count = Upgrade.objects.filter(building__town=building.town).count()
```